# Running Cygwin Inferior Shell in Emacs

Tags: windows, emacs, cygwin

I am running [Cygwin as an Inferior Shell in Emacs](https://superuser.com/questions/61484/using-emacs-to-control-command-line-processes).  Here's the basic step I am following:

- C-u M-x shell (rename the buffer to cygwin)
- cd \cygwin
- cygwin.bat

Here's what I see:

```
C:\cygwin>cygwin
cygwin
]0;~
[32muser1@mymachine [33m~[0m
$
```

If I run cygwin.bat outside of emacs, it gives me:

```
user1@mymachine ~
$
```

I could almost deal with the extra characters, but when I try ls here's the result:

```
$ ls
bash: $'ls\r': command not found
```

I must be doing something wrong.  Any suggestions?

EDIT:  M-x ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on fixed the prompt, but the system is still not able to decode the ls command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the fix for the unix linefeed junk:
http://osdir.com/ml/emacs.windows/2007-12/msg00007.html

Basically, just run:

```
M-x set-buffer-process-coding-system
```

with 'undecided-unix and 'undecided-unix parameters.

Also, change the prompt to be:

```
export PS1="\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$"
```

The default PS1 causes ugly errors.